# What could I use to generate names of element locators?

Tags: javascript, css, selenium, xpath

I need to generate names of element locators for a project I am currently doing using Selenium IDE. I can use xpaths, css or dom to find elements and use them to generate names of elements. Can anyone suggest what to use to extract meaningful names from css, xpath or dom? For example, I can use

```
//li[@id='item1c4994198e']/div/div/a/img
```

as my xpath to get to the element and use the id attribute to generate a name for the element.

Answer (score 1):

@Vaibhav: Fetching elements with right locater is the Heart of Selenium. Now here are few things which you should always remember.

Never make your script dependent on Absolute Xpath .(i.e path from source like      /html.body......).  Try to use plug ins like firebug to generate       Xpath..   You may also come across a situation where the path    generated    by firebug  may not detect your desired element on the    page so option    is to use relative path. If you still need more    info on it ..you can    follow below links

http://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/xpath-firebug-firepath/

Answer (score 0):

It is always better to use relative xpath, if you are unable to get the element locator then go for absolute xpath, DOM is limited to Selenium RC only.